# Properly convert blob audio to webm format

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, webm, web-mediarecorder, tone.js

Hy, I am using tone.js to record audio using my mic and then downloading the audio.

Here is my code;

```js
function test() {

var mic, recorder;
    
recorder = new Tone.Recorder();
mic = new Tone.UserMedia();
recorder = new Tone.Recorder();
mic.connect(recorder);
mic.open();
recorder.start();
    

    
setTimeout(async () => {

    // the recorded audio is returned as a blob
    const recording = await recorder.stop();
    mic.close();
    recording.date = Date.now();
    recording.name = `${Date.now()}.webm`;
    recording.type = "audio/webm";
    recording.codecs = "opus";
    recording.length = "120";
    
    // Create Object URL
    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(recording);
    //instance.publishState("audio_blob", blobUrl);
    const anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.download = `${Date.now()}.webm`;
    anchor.href = blobUrl;
    anchor.click();
    
}, 4000);
}
```

Here is the link from where I got the reference for this code.
[Recorder - UserMedia API](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/Recorder)

### Problem

Now when I play the downloaded audio file, it does not show the audio length.
I have tried adding length property to audio blob using `recording.length = "120";` but it still does not add the length to audio file.
I need to know how can I add length to my audio file. Also which codec and format should I use. When I try to use mp3 format, the downloaded file is broken. Why is that ?

You can use the codepen for testing the API. Its a bit different from my code but the concept is same. [CodePen sample](https://codepen.io/naotokui/pen/abBvBmW)

Comment: `navigator.MediaRecorder` emits webm data it captures from microphones, compresses, and boxes in WebM. Those are not trivial tasks. But (AFAIK) MediaRecorder doesn't have a path to accept uncompressed audio samples from Blobs. There are server-side apps to do the compression and boxing.  Try searching for "compress pcm audio in browser Javascript."  You may, in some browsers, be able to use [.getDisplayMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) to capture audio being played by your browser. You have a hard requirement, sorry to say.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the length of the audio file just modify the 4000 to a higher value.

```
setTimeout(async () => {
   //.......content.........
}, 10000);
```

This is the parameter that will control the duration of the recording in the setTimeout function.
I am not sure about how to convert to mp3. I am trying to figure that out myself, let me know if you find anything.

Comment: OP is trying to "show the audio length" of an already recorded file (more specifically, to include metadata of playtime for 3rd-party audio players to read). They made no mention of trying to change the available recording time.